# Contact form with dynamic dropdown and filter

Tags: php, functions, forms, dropdown, plugin-contact-form-7

A client wants to create a contact form for a moto parts store that allows users to choose their moto make-model-year. They want this information to provide better assistance after the contact.
They want something like this:

[image]

---

but inside a contact form like this:

[image]

I've just read a blog post on "How to create dynamically populated cascading dropdown-lists for Contact Form 7".
I am new to programming, I don't know anything about PHP.
So I tried step by step this:

1. I created my database .csv file.
2. I uploaded the file at public_html/wp-content/uploads/make-model-year.csv (Is it the correct path?)
3. Then I pasted this function to functions.php:

```php
<?php
function ajax_cf7_populate_values() {

        // read the CSV file in the $makes_models_years array

    $makes_models_years = array();
    $uploads_folder = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'];
    $file = fopen($uploads_folder.'\make_model_year.csv', 'r');

    $firstline = true;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        if ($firstline) {
            $firstline = false;
            continue;
        }
        $makes_models_years[$line[0]][$line[1]][] = $line[2];

    }
    fclose($file);

        // setup the initial array that will be returned to the the client side script as a JSON object.

    $return_array = array(
            'makes' => array_keys($makes_models_years),
            'models' => array(),
            'years' => array(),
            'current_make' => false,
            'current_model' => false
        );

        // collect the posted values from the submitted form

    $make = key_exists('make', $_POST) ? $_POST['make'] : false;
    $model = key_exists('model', $_POST) ? $_POST['model'] : false;
    $year = key_exists('year', $_POST) ? $_POST['year'] : false;

        // populate the $return_array with the necessary values

    if ($make) {
        $return_array['current_make'] = $make;
        $return_array['models'] = array_keys($makes_models_years[$make]);
        if ($model) {
        $return_array['current_model'] = $model;
        $return_array['years'] = $makes_models_years[$make][$model];
        if ($year) {
                $return_array['current_year'] = $year;
            }
            }
        }

        // encode the $return_array as a JSON object and echo it
        
        echo json_encode($return_array);
        wp_die();

}

// These action hooks are needed to tell WordPress that the cf7_populate_values() function needs to be called
// if a script is POSTing the action : 'cf7_populate_values'

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cf7_populate_values', 'ajax_cf7_populate_values' );
```

But when I try to save `functions.php`, it alerts "Something has gone wrong. Your change could not be saved. Please try again. You may also have to manually correct it and upload the file via FTP."

I really don't know where to begin, because my knowledge of programming is so basic. I am using Wordpress, Elementor and Contact Form 7.

I would be so thankful if you could show me the way and help me with this.

Comment: there's probably a syntax error in the final `functions.php` that you're trying to save, but without seeing the full file it's difficult if not impossible to tell you what it is, though I suspect that what you shared is not the entire file but just the part you pasted in, and it's not liking that you opened a new PHP tag inside another one. Eitherway, Contact Form 7 and other 3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, this isn't a place to get help with 3rd party plugins.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know this wasn't the place to ask this. I pasted the function exactly as the creator of it says. But maybe it is for a different PHP version?